# c++ inheritance - same method name with different argument type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, inheritance

I'm trying to compile following code in VC++ 2010:

```
class Base
{
public:
    std::wstring GetString(unsigned id) const
    {
        return L"base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    std::wstring GetString(const std::wstring& id) const
    {
        return L"derived";
    }
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    Derived d;

    d.GetString(1);
}
```

My understanding was that Derived will have two methods:

```
std::wstring GetString(unsigned id) const
std::wstring GetString(const std::wstring& id) const
```

so my code should compile succesfully. Visual C++ 2010 however reports following error:

```
test.cpp(32): error C2664: 'Derived::GetString' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const std::wstring &'
      Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const std::wstring'
      No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

What am I doing wrong? The code works perfectly when I use it this way:

```
Derived d;
Base base = d;
base.GetString(1);
```

or when both variants of GetString are defined in same class.

Any ideas? I would like to avoid explicit typecasting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Derived::GetString` hides `Base::GetString`.<sup>*</sup>  To solve this, do the following:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::GetString;

    std::wstring GetString(const std::wstring& id) const
    {
        return L"derived";
    }
};
```

---

<sub>* For fairly obscure reasons that Scott Meyers explains in Chapter 50 of "Effective C++".</sub>

See also  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9.

Comment: +1 Alternatively you can manually select the method: `d.base::GetString(1)` but this has the nasty side effect of disabling dynamic dispatch (if the member function was `virtual`, which is not the case)

Comment: using Base::GetString makes perfect sense. I thought the compiler is a bit more intelligent and would throw such error only when arguments of the method in base and derived are somehow compatible.

Comment: btw, this also explains why I could not call "base" GetString from in the derived class without explicitly typing Base::GetString or __super::GetString.